# Displaying messages after every step of code execution

Tags: php

i have a snippet of code like this :

```
 $response = "<div style='font-size:18px;margin-top:2em;text-align:center;color:#173f5f;>";
 $response .= "Intializing sequence...";
    echo $response;
    $response .= "Starting compression of folders...";
    echo $response;
    $response .= "Compressing all photos now...";
    echo $response;
    $ph = compress('photos');
    $response .= "Photo compression complete.";
    $response .= "Compressing all signatures now...";
    echo $response;
    $sg = compress('signatures');
    $response .= "Signature compression complete.";
    $response .= "Compressing all excel files now...";
    echo $response;
    $excel = compress('uploads');
    $response .= "Excel files compression complete.</div>";
    echo $response;
```

i want the messages to be displayed after every line of `compress` function call but right now, its running the each call of the functions in a bunch and then displaying the messages in a bunch at the end that too every line repeated.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Someone Please guide on making it real time..

Answer (score 0):

I think the others have missed the point of the question.  You want each line of each to appear in "real time" as the script is processing rather than on execution completion.
PHP by default doesn't output the buffer until the script execution has been completed or the buffer is full.

You can manually flush the buffer to screen when you want using this function.

```
function fcflush()
{
    static $output_handler = null;
    if ($output_handler === null) {
        $output_handler = @ini_get('output_handler');
    }
    if ($output_handler == 'ob_gzhandler') {
        // forcing a flush with this is very bad
        return;
    }
    flush();
    if (function_exists('ob_flush') AND function_exists('ob_get_length') AND ob_get_length() !== false) {
        @ob_flush();
    } else if (function_exists('ob_end_flush') AND function_exists('ob_start') AND function_exists('ob_get_length') AND ob_get_length() !== FALSE) {
        @ob_end_flush();
        @ob_start();
    }
}
```

And you use it in your code like this

```
echo "<div style='font-size:18px;margin-top:2em;text-align:center;color:#173f5f;>";
fcflush();
echo "Intializing sequence...";
fcflush();
echo "Starting compression of folders...";
fcflush();
echo $response .= "Compressing all photos now...";
fcflush();
    $ph = compress('photos');
echo "Photo compression complete.";
fcflush();
echo "Compressing all signatures now...";
fcflush();
    $sg = compress('signatures');
echo "Signature compression complete.";
fcflush();
echo "Compressing all excel files now...";
fcflush();
    $excel = compress('uploads');
echo "Excel files compression complete.</div>";
fcflush();
```

Also just echo out the lines directly ratehr than assigning them to $response then echoing out that.

Comment: You got it just right. understood what i really want, the real time message output, But i tried your code and after the click of the button when the browser is directed to this php code, its finishes in bunch again and this time didnt even display anything.

Comment: It shouldn't do as long as you're calling the function and the function is in your code.  if it is then are you running some form of cache or are you setting buffering else where in your code? the fcflush() function forces the buffers to be flushed to screen and so gives the appearance of real time as its processing.

Comment: No dave, i am not running any kind of cache and the function is very well inside the code, the function is written after the above code still its performing the functions but not displaying anything even in bunch let alone real time

Comment: Wierd actually just tested it on a windows machine and it doesn't flush the buffers until the processing is completed but on the linux machines it runs perfectly and outputs each line on each itteration of the loop rather than all at once.

Comment: Wierd. Its gotta be a config issue of some kind not entirely sure all the code does is its a nice wrapper function to flush all of the php buffers to screen there's nothing special there but what appears to be happening to you (and me on windows) is php is holding onto the buffers and not flushing them on request